# Combining rows with a sql report designer

Tags: sql, sql-server, report-designer

i'm very new to sql programming and i want to know how to combine rows with same id as seen below? i'm using a sql report designer. i tried using **group by** with **having count** code but it does not return the values that i'm expecting.

this is the result of my code:

```
ID  TYPE    PART        
4   spares  valve       
3   spares  bulb        
4   spares  pump        
12  time    motor
```

and this is my expected result:

```
ID  TYPE    PART
4   spares  valve, pump
3   spares  bulb
12  time    motor
```

Comment: The term 'combine' is unclear. What do you mean? join? please go into details.

Comment: please, post what you have tried till now, the expected result and the one you got back with your query.

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: It's still not clear what your problem is

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT GROUPCONCAT(concat(PART) separator ',') into PARTS 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE ID = ID;
```